# Does the Emacs manual recommend the Latin-1 language environment over utf-8?

Tags: manual

In the Emacs Manual (50.4.2) as an example of init file examples we have this by Richard Stallaman:

> Set up defaults for the Latin-1 character set, which supports most of
> the languages of Western Europe.
>
> `(set-language-environment "Latin-1")`

I am curious as to why the manual not suggest `utf-8`? Could this be an historical artifact? If so, why has it never been updated? Is this merely and example and not a recommendation? Perhaps there is an advantage to using `Latin 1`?

Comment: The title of the section is "Init *Examples*" - emphasis added. No recommendation is implied: it's just a list of "You want to do <this>? Here is how". Best thing to do is: nothing. If it works out of the box without you doing anything, you avoid a lot of hassles. Eventually, you might run into situations where the default does not work for whatever reason. At that point, you can start delving into arcana, but by then you should be a seasoned Emacser and able to find your way through the documentation to solve all problems.

Comment: If utf-8 is now the default, it follows that there is no need to add utf as the language environment to dot emacs? If so, do I need: ```(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)```

Comment: I have LANG=en_US.UTF-8 set by my system and I set nothing in my emacs init. I would  suggest that you start with that setup (i.e.  doing nothing in emacs) and see how it works.

Comment: I set that in my .bashrc (I am on msys2 in Windows). The coding system in Emacs is now utf-8-dos.

Comment: @Edman please be sure to ask a single question. Which question would you like us to answer, here?

Comment: Apologies for the layered nature of my previous inquiries. To make it clear, my primary question was the one posted. As a follow-up, I then wondered what is the default environment for Emacs, and the best way to set it if not UTF-8. NickD suggested I set it in my system, resulting in the coding being set to `utf-8-dos` without the need to make changes to my init.el. A final question arises from this: is `utf-8-dos` a better choice than `utf-8-unix` if running Emacs on Windows in msys2? Maybe you want me to post another question?

Comment: Yes (to both questions :-) )